# What is a good checklist for risk based testing?

Tags: test-creation, risk-analysis

Few days ago, I have checked the tests of my node project. There are a lot of tests, but I ask myself which tests are necessary and which are not. I searched google and found very interesting strategy of "risk based testing". Now I'm looking for a good checklist for risk based testing.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of risk based testing is that *your* context defines what the risks might be. What is important to me is not necessarily important to you. So there won't be a checklist that will work for everybody.
Having said that: you might find this [HTSM](http://www.satisfice.com/tools/htsm.pdf) explanation useful. To guide your thinking about what could be risky in your situation and what area would warrant some better investigation/testing. But don't rely on lists only!

For more reading look here for [James Bach](http://www.satisfice.com) and [Michael Bolton](http://www.developsense.com) and [here](http://www.developsense.com/articles/2006-10-MasterOfYourDomain.pdf). Another great source is [Cem Kaner](http://www.testingeducation.org/BBST/testdesign/) with his BBST series on Test Design.

Comment: "So there won't be a checklist that will work for everybody." The  risks and the software are different between projects. But the steps to identify and weight the risks are the same. I'm not experienced on risk base testing and looking for people who practice this longer time and know the important points (THE checklist :-)

Comment: i.e. one point on this checklist is, "validate the potential damage of a failed test case ==> NO damage NO test"

Comment: I think the HTSM is a good _practical_ checklist. It makes you think about what might be worth looking into, depending on your specific context. To cite Cem Kaner: "Risk-based testing starts from an idea of how the program could fail. Then design tests that try to expose problems of that type."

Comment: HTSM is a possible startpoint. But it is like you look for a travle guide for swiss but take a travle guide for europa :-(
I think the checklist can only be created by people with experience in risk base testing.

Comment: Believe me: the guys I am pointing you too _do_ have a lot of experience. The point of having Europe is that it gives you an idea of where Switzerland is and how it is connected to it's neighbors. Maybe you thought you needed to be there but is actually Austria you are looking for. Anyway... to give a sense of [testing without a map](http://www.developsense.com/articles/2005-01-TestingWithoutAMap.pdf). And the general point being: you know the best what might be a risk to you. your product or your company. Go from there. What, if X fails, would happen? Would that be bad? If so: how to find it?

Comment: I agree! But this is no a checklist (a tool to avoid misdirections, to save time and money) :-(

Comment: When I use the HTSM 'Quality Criteria Categories' list, for instance, it helps me think of areas that might be of risk (e.g. if this fails is that a big problem and to whom?). To me assessing risks is about asking questions. Maybe my point is that there is not really such a 'tool' what you are looking for, or at least that I know off. I guess your best tool you already own ;-) (small disclaimer: I have been teaching the [BBST courses](http://altom.training/), including Test Design with Cem Kaner). The BBST courses are also offered [here](https://www.associationforsoftwaretesting.org/courses/)